# Kerberos Password Change Web Interface Suggestions

Tags: debian, password, kerberos

Debian 6
MIT Kerberos i.e. krb5

We can change our Kerberos passwords by using kpasswd at the command line.

We'd like to offer users the option to change their Kerberos passwords in a friendly web interface. Is there an existing web application or script which would make this possible? I've googled around and I haven't found anything promising yet. Any leads on existing tools which do this or how to do this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[WebAuth](http://webauth.stanford.edu/), a Kerberos-backed authentication system for web applications, provides a Kerberos password changing facility. It does far more than that, but any solution you deploy ought to be protected by WebAuth or something similar (Cosign, Shibboleth, CAS) anyway.